# TYPO3 set_no_cache() triggering unnecessarily

Tags: caching, typo3, error-log, typo3-7.6.x

I am using TYPO3 7.6.11 . Some of my extension have no_cache = 1/set_no_cache = 1 forced in the url.

By checking the error log, I'm continuously seeing errors as

> cms: $TSFE->set_no_cache() was triggered. Reason: no_cache is
> requested via GET parameter. Caching is disabled!
>
> cms:
> $TSFE->set_no_cache() was triggered. Reason: no_cache has been set
> before the page was generated - safety check. Caching is disabled!

Also in the install tool,

**$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['disableNoCacheParameter'] = '0';**

Basically after googling possible solutions.. I found out setting **disableNoCacheParameter** will solve the issue.. But it'll be useless in situations where I need pages to be cached (like fe_login and all)

If some of you guyz ever came across a situation like this one above, I'd like to hear from you. :)

I don't want the error log to show this error. It's totally disturbing. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you don't need the parameter `no_cache=1` at all as if a plugin should not be cached, it can be switched to be a `USER_INT`. Same for TypoScript as there is the `COA_INT` content object which also makes its content not cached.